# Doing an in-order traversal on a binary tree in Haskell using a fold

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, fold

I'm trying to implement an in-order traversal function using a modified version of fold in Haskell:

```
foldT :: (u -> u -> u) -> (a -> u) -> Tree a -> u
foldT f g (Tip a) = g a
foldT f g (Node l r) = f (foldT f g l) (foldT f g r)
```

But I'm getting stuck with how to implement the function, my attempt is:

```
inorderT :: Ord a => Tree a -> [a]
inorderT = foldT (\x l r -> l ++ x ++ r) []
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Error messages:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘[a] -> [a]’
• In the first argument of ‘foldT’, namely
    ‘(\ x l r -> l ++ x ++ r)’
  In the expression: foldT (\ x l r -> l ++ x ++ r) []
  In an equation for ‘inorderT’:
      inorderT = foldT (\ x l r -> l ++ x ++ r) []
• Relevant bindings include
    inorderT :: Tree a -> [a]
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?  And what do you think the error message means?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the error message, it's got to be a problem with the types but I'm unsure on how to approach solving it

Comment: Now make a guess as to what the error message means.  It's pointing you to a specific section of your code -- what could be wrong?  Post your guess.  (Showing effort like this both helps you figure it out and endears people to help you since it shows you have put thought into it)

Comment: This isn't homework, it's exam revision

Comment: so I'm guessing that the lambda function is wrong as it's not compatible with `foldT`?

Comment: right!  The `(u -> u -> u)` function takes two arguments and you've given a lambda with three arguments.  How might you fix this?  Hint: What type is `u`?  (it's the same as the return type of your function `inorderT`)

Comment: okay, so the type of  `u` is `Node`? I know this doesn't work but is it any closer: `foldT (\x r -> [x]: [r]) []` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have reconstructed the tree data type from the foldT definition. Check out it is not in the `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)` form commonly used, so your  `(\x l r -> l ++ x ++ r)` is wrong.

Check your code, and later see if this is what you need:

```
data Tree a = Tip a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)

foldT :: (u -> u -> u) -> (a -> u) -> Tree a -> u
foldT f g (Tip a)    = g a
foldT f g (Node l r) = f (foldT f g l) (foldT f g r)

inorderT :: Tree a -> [a]
inorderT = foldT (\l r -> l ++ r) (\x -> [x])
```